# Cannot Sign In to Microsoft Azure via WebMatrix

Tags: azure, webmatrix

I am trying to publish my site to Azure via web matrix. However, when I try to sign in via WebMatrix, I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2yN8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsrbX.png)

The following is the details of the error:
*Quick Start - Microsoft WebMatrix
authentication_failed: The system cannot locate the resource specified.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException: authentication_failed: The system cannot locate the resource specified.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ExceptionHelper.ThrowServiceException(String error, String errorDescription)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenFromSts(String resource, String clientId, Uri redirectUri, String userId, PromptBehavior promptBehavior, String extraQueryParameters)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenInternal(String resource, String clientId, Uri redirectUri, String userId, PromptBehavior promptBehavior, String extraQueryParameters)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.AzureTokenManager.AcquireToken(String userId, String extraQueryParameters)*

I dont have any any clue how to resolve this. Any help in this is highly appreciated.